# javasctipt/jquery array parsing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was looking for a picklist template in javascript and came across this code.

[JsFiddle for picklist](https://jsfiddle.net/gabrielr47/8ek53b1f/)

Which has the following code to parse through a from what i am assuming a Jquery object array.

```
<script>

     var val = {
        01: {id: 01, text: 'test2'},
        02: {id: 02, text: 'test3'},
        03: {id: 03, text: 'test2'},
     };

     var pick = $("#pickList").pickList({data: val});

     $("#getSelected").click(function () {
        console.log(pick.getValues(val));
        alert(pick.getValues());
     });
     </script>
```

> Where the #pickList is a function which populates data onto a form.

Now when I run this using the button "#getSelected" , I can see in chrome developer options that it is fetching the data from the form but in some sort of an key value pair.

Now, When I try to `alert(pick.getValues());`

I get an alert with `[object Object]` and not the value inside the array.

Can someone help me to know how to parse the array so that i can get the value of the "text"

Below is a screenshot of the Chrome dev console.
[Screenshot of chrome dev options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29Vka.jpg)

Comment: Instead of `alert(pick.getValues());` use `console.log(pick.getValues());` and see the console output in your dev console.

Comment: @DavidR Console.log works actually, how do I post it to the server? I was thinking if I can get it to alert then I can move the value to a variable and then post that to the server.

Comment: Then try this `alert(JSON.stringify(pick.getValues()))`

Comment: @DavidR Wow that works. Can you post that as an answer so that i can mark it as solved? THank you so much

Comment: Done mate!. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `JSON.stringify` inside your `alert` statement like this,

```
alert(JSON.stringify(pick.getValues()));
```

Hope this helps!